# Mapping Plug N Play Devices to PCI Slot IDs, C#

Tags: c#, hardware

I have a certain number of external devices, let's call them Things.
Each Thing interfaces with the computer through a PnP Card plugged into a PCI slot.
Each Card has ports for 4 Things.
I need to obtain a UID for each Thing that persists and is consistent between reboots.
Note that the Things do not have a built in UID that I can access.

My idea to solve this problem is to get a UID for each port on the Cards. It seems to me that I just have to figure out which PCI slot each Card is plugged in to. That isn't going to change on reboot, and certainly the ports are going to be in the same order... so I can essentially label each port with the UID and know which UID each Thing is associated with.

I have done a fair bit of searching to figure out what C# objects would be of most use. The closest I have found is the `ManagementObjectSearcher` object from the `System.Management` library. Here is some simple code I wrote to see if this would get me what I want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDsearch();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void IDsearch()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
    }
}
```

This produces output like the following for every PnP devices on my computer:

```
DeviceID: ACPI\GENUINEINTEL_-_INTEL64_FAMILY_6_MODEL_60_-_INTEL(R)_CORE(TM)_I7-4790_CPU_@_3.60GHZ\_1
Description: Intel Processor

DeviceID: USB\VID_0CF3&PID_3004\ALASKA_DAY_2006
Description: Dell Wireless 1535C Bluetooth Device
```

This would fit my requirements if I could also obtain the PCI slot number.

I also came across the `Win32_SystemSlot` class, but this does not seem to give me a description of what is actually plugged into the slot! So at this point, I can get descriptions without PCI slots... and PCI slots without descriptions. I just can't map them together, which is what I need. I must be overlooking something or not asking the right question, because this strikes me as a pretty common thing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Keith,  I don't know the answer to you question but seems to me that you need to find a way to get the ID of the device not the port. The Things should have something to identify them...  look at this... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-for-pci-devices

Comment: @GreatJobBob. The Things do in fact have a description. They are just not unique between different Things. I am trying to ID and differentiate multiple Things that are hooked up at the same time. In other words, although I have an ID, to get a UID i need to map to the card and port.

Comment: The Card that your things are connecting to should have a UID so can you not scan for the Card UID to know which PCI slot your card is installed into?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I also have a requirement to report devices and which PCI slot they reside in, if possible.

Comment: Nope, I never solved this. Ended up using a separate computer for each "thing" rather than a single motherboard and using message queuing. That actually made more sense for my particular needs anyway. But no I never really found an answer to this even after throwing a lot of research at it.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds extremely fragile, what if the machine get moved and the devices get plugged into different ports. Is is a personal project or something you are trying to distribute.  If the latter you should find another way. Are the "Things" of your own creation?  If so you need to include the ability for each to have a unique identifier. If not you should contact the manufacturer and inquire.  Trying to identify it by port may cause you lots of headaches down the road

Comment: Your points make sense, but they don't really help my particular issue. Indeed I agree with you... but I can't just remanufacture the Things to have built in UIDs. Note that other devices like graphics cards, at least that I have seen, do not appear to have unit specific UIDs... just model specific.

Comment: Okay Keith that's fair, but with the graphic cards we don't need to track what was sent to each between reboots.  Maybe you can give more details on what you are trying to do :)

Comment: The Things are cameras. I need to associate the output of each camera with the particular camera from which it originated. I abstracted the question to Things though because I dont see why it should matter... just trying to keep the question as clean as possible. The solution im looking for is at the PnP or PCI slot level... not the type of device level.

Comment: Hi Keith. Can you see the cameras in the Windows Device Manager? If you can then go to the details page and see if you can see the port info. Should be lots of info on the details page from the dropdown. If you can then at least you will know that it is possible. If Windows doesn't see it then in could be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a combination of the `Win32_Bus` and the `Win32_DeviceBus` classes.

The `Win32_Bus` represents a physical bus as seen by a computer running a Windows operating system ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-bus)). The bus type can be PCI and bus number seems to be an enumeration of the different physical PCI buses.

The `Win32_DeviceBus` relates a system bus and a logical device using the bus. This class is used to discover which devices are on which bus ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-devicebus)). On my platform the device associated with a bus was always a `Win32_PnPEntity`.

Using these classes you should be able to find the physical bus attributes from a  given `Win32_PnPEntity`.